# Generate mac addresses in certain range in bash

Tags: bash

I need some help generating all mac addresses with in some range in a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    mac='00:00:00:00'
    index=16000
    start_index=53
    
    for i in $( eval echo {$start_index..$((start_index+index))})
    do
        bridge fdb add printf "$mac:%x\n" $i dev sw1p1 static master
    done
```

managed to do so in python

```
mac = '00:00:00:00'
index = 16000
start_index = 53
for number in range(start_index, start_index + index):
    hex_num = hex(number)[2:].rjust(4, '0')
    entry = "{}:{}{}:{}{}".format(mac, *hex_num)
    os.system(f"bridge fdb add {entry} dev sw1p1 static master)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the *number* into two octets using arithmetic expansions, and convert them to base 16 using `printf`.

```
# define mac, start_index, index here
# assume index <= 65535
for ((num=start_index; num<=index; num++)); do
  printf -v sfx ':%02X:%02X' $((num>>8)) $((num&255))
  bridge fdb add "${mac}${sfx}" dev sw1p1 static master
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a decimal number into the hexadecimal mac address format

- First convert to a padded hexadecimal number: `printf %016x\\n "$i"`
- Then insert the `:` after every other digit: `... | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//'`
  or `sed 's/../:&/g2'` with GNU sed.

Since you build your mac address from a fixed prefix and generated suffix, we use `printf %08x` and `sed 's/../:&/g'` instead, to print only the suffix.

For the loop I'd recommend `seq $a $b` instead of `$(eval {$a..$b})`.

```
prefix=00:00:00:00
start=53
length=16000
seq "$start" "$((start + length))" |
while read i; do
  suffix=$(printf %08x\\n "$i" | sed 's/../:&/g')
  bridge fdb add "$prefix$suffix" dev sw1p1 static master
done
```

As long as you don't run into `ARG_MAX` you can drop the loop completely:

```
printf %08x\\n $(seq "$start" "$((start + length))") | sed 's/../:&/g' |
xargs -I {} bridge fdb add "$prefix"{} dev sw1p1 static master
```

Comment: I use 00:00:00:00 only as a prefix I need a real address eventually.  
00:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: @DavidMeu Right. Missed that point until I inspected you python script in detail. I hope the revised answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try

```sh
start_index=53
index=16000
for i in `seq $start_index $((start_index+index))`
do
    bridge fdb add `printf %08X $i|sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//'` dev sw1p1 static master
done
```

Comment: line 7: printf: seq: invalid number
Invalid mac address 0
Invalid mac address 35
Invalid mac address 3E:B5

Comment: Invalid mac address 00:00:02:78 seems like 2 octates missing

Comment: Tried:

bridge fdb add `printf %012X $i|sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//'` dev sw1p1 static master 
but got RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Comment: Would the command work if you replace the `printf` and `sed` part by literal MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

Me too!

```
seq 53 $((53+16000)) |
awk '{printf "00:00:00:00:%02x:%02x\n", $1/255, $1%255}' |
xargs -i{} echo bridge fdb add {} dev sw1p1 static master
```

or maybe:

```
mac='00:00:00:00'
seq 53 $((53+16000)) |
awk '{printf "%02x:%02x\n", $1/255, $1%255}' |
xargs -i{} echo bridge fdb add "$mac:{}" dev sw1p1 static master
```

Some more awk, with I think gawk extension `rshift` and `and`, should be (slightly) faster:

```
awk -vB=53 -vE=$((53+16000)) 'BEGIN { for(i=B;i<E;i++) printf "%02x:%02x\n", rshift(i, 8), and(i, 0xff); }' <&- |
xargs -i{} echo bridge fdb add "$mac:{}" dev sw1p1 static maste
```